# Slice/Splice one array into another without modifying the originals

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a freecodecamp challenge, in which one array has to be copied into another at a given index, without altering the original arrays. I came up with my own solution, and when I `console.log();` wrap each function input, I get the desired results, as far as I can tell. However, it is not passing the tests. I did not use a for loop and tried to make my solution as simple as possible. I will display both my solution and their solution.

Below is some code highlighting both:

MY SOLUTION:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  var vArr1 = [...arr1];
  var vArr2 = [...arr2];

  var slice1 = vArr1.slice(0);
  var endBits = vArr2.splice(n);


  return [...vArr2, slice1, endBits];   
}
```

For example, `frankenSplice(["claw", "tentacle"], ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "toes"], 2)` should return `["head", "shoulders", "claw", "tentacle", "knees", "toes"]`, and it does as far as I can tell when I use the console (does not pass test though for that stipulation).

THEIR SOLUTION:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let localArray = arr2.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    localArray.splice(n, 0, arr1[i]);
    n++;
  }
  return localArray;
}
```

I just don't see a need to use a for loop if I can do it in my simple line of logic. I'm guessing either I am going about it completely wrong or I just have to make a simple tweak to solve the tests. Thanks for helping.

Comment: This might be better over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh cool, thank you. What's the difference between these two subsections of "stack"? I'm new to coding and especially to the ins and outs of this website.

Comment: @imvain2 I do have to wait about 40 minutes to post again. Oh well. I spose I'll just move on and use their solution for now. :) I'll try to write it myself of course but it is hard to take the hundreds of challenges I've done prior and integrate them into a more complex challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve `["head", "shoulders", "claw", "tentacle", "knees", "toes"]` as a result from your function, you would just have to change your `return` to:
`return [...vArr2, ...slice1, ...endBits];`.

If you're aiming to make your function as short as possible, you could go with a one liner:

`const frankenSplice = (arr1, arr2, n) => [ ...arr2.slice(0, n), ...arr1, ...arr2.slice(n)];`

Comment: That did it! Makes sense since my new variables I made are still arrays and need a rest operator to be copied correctly. @dziraf

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS MY SOLUTION:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  var vArr1 = [...arr1];
  var vArr2 = [...arr2];

  var slice1 = vArr1.slice(0);
  var endBits = vArr2.splice(n);


  return [...vArr2, ...slice1, ...endBits];   
}
```

Maybe the for loop is somehow the more correct and conventional way or more elegant way to do this, but I like my solution for now. :)